# Achieving intended result from fmod or similar in spite of floating point arithmetic

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy, fmod

**Background**

Consider the validation of three doubles `low`, `width` and `high` such that the following three rules hold true:

1. `low < high`;
2. `width > 0`; and
3. `width` fits into `(high - low)` "exactly" a whole number of times.

Essentially, the three values should specify a range that is to be split up into a certain number of bins, each of "exactly" equal width, with no part of the range unnaccounted for.

For example:

**(A)** `low = -0.5`, `width = 0.005` and `high = 0.5`

would specify a range with a **valid** bin width, since "exactly" 200 full bins can be created, whereas

**(B)** `low = -0.5`, `width = 0.275` and `high = 0.5`

would specify a range with an **invalid** bin width, since 3 full bins could be created but part of the range is not covered by those bins.

**The Problem**

What is the best way approach the third validation rule, given the floating-point nature of doubles?

My first naive attempt consisted of:

`fmod( high - low, width ) == 0.0`

but unfortunately fmod returns 0.005 for example **(A)** - my debugger tells me that the double of 0.005 actually holds the value of `0.0050000000000000001`.

Should I be home-brewing my own solution to include tolerances, or is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

This is what I have currently:

```
bool valid(double range, double width, double tolerance = 0.000000001)
{
  assert(width > 0 && range > 0);

  while( range > 0 && range > tolerance )
  {
    range -= width;
  }

  return abs(range) <= tolerance;
}
```

Note the complete and utter arbitrariness of the default value of tolerance ...

Comment: Why are you using doubles? This is an application they're not particularly well suited for. Why not use rationals or fixed point?

Comment: Is it necessarily a failure for the width ofthe final histogram bin to be narrower than the other bins to the order of 10^-10? It is in the nature of floating point systems that you're going to have little fuzzy bits at the end, after all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - The values are actually typed in by users in a GUI, and so arrive to me as strings I could easily cast to whatever I choose.  Perhaps the answer does lie in simply not using doubles.

Comment: @Rook - We are using FFT's further down the line that require things to be pretty exact, but this code does not belong to me so I'm not sure *how* exact.  To further complicate matters, the code is Fortran compiled using F2Py, so the doubles are going from C++ to Python to Fortran...

Comment: I probably need to get a clearer handle on my requirements / the problem space.  I had hoped for a simple "duh, just use the uber-simple, in-built library function [____]" but that was just folly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using a tolerance for double comparisons is a reasonable one. The only thing you need now is to do the rest of your requirements analysis to determine how haccurate you really need to be :)

If you know your maximum precision, multiply up to integer values for the comparison.